# Error adding supported language on my action on google

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

In my smart home action on google I selected all Locations like explained here: https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/publishing but I can't add any language in my project settings like explained here https://developers.google.com/actions/console/publishing#adding_app_details_for_other_languages because every time I get an error saving languages informations. 
I've been trying to change the languages for a week and in two different project but it still does not work. 
Anyone know why? Is there something wrong in my project settings?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The error is a generic "There was an error saving language information". Selected languages are English and Italian and I can't save any change.

Comment: If you open the dev tools, do you see any notable errors, or is everything pretty generic?

Comment: I see only that the POST request to https://console.actions.google.com/u/0/m/actions/agents/i18n/updateLanguageSet gets Error 500

Answer (score 0):

The language options for Google Home projects can be selected through the menu (3 dots), then selecting Project Settings. Then select the Languages tab, and choose the languages you want to support.

Note that the other Actions on Google project types now use a different infrastructure than Smart Home projects, hence what you see in the Assistant documentation might be different for Smart Home. For the list of languages currently supported for Smart Home can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits#supported-languages).